# cabal install regex-dfa fails

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm trying to install the `regex-dfa` package. I installed other regex packages like `regex-tdfa`, and they worked fine.

However, when I run `sudo cabal install regex-dfa` I get an error message:

```
Resolving dependencies...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/regex-dfa-0.91-9125/regex-dfa-0.91/Setup.hs, /tmp/regex-dfa-0.91-9125/regex-dfa-0.91/dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking /tmp/regex-dfa-0.91-9125/regex-dfa-0.91/dist/setup/setup ...
Configuring regex-dfa-0.91...
Warning: No 'build-type' specified. If you do not need a custom Setup.hs or
./configure script then use 'build-type: Simple'.
Building regex-dfa-0.91...
Preprocessing library regex-dfa-0.91...

Text/Regex/DFA/Wrap.hs:1:16: Warning:
    -fglasgow-exts is deprecated: Use individual extensions instead

<no location info>: 
Failing due to -Werror.
Failed to install regex-dfa-0.91
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
regex-dfa-0.91 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1):

The package is very old, the last (and the only) upload was in 2007. Don't use it if you can. Or contact the maintainer and ask him to update the package.

To fix this particular issue, you can `cabal unpack regex-dfa`, remove the `-Werror` and then `cabal install` it. But I'm not sure you will get another build error after that.